# Error when converting DICOM image to pixel_array using tensorflow_io

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pydicom, medical-imaging

I am trying to create a TensorFlow Dataset from DICOM images using the tf.data API and tensorflow_io, and I want to perform some pre-processing using Hounsfield units from the images. The DICOM images have a shape of (512,512). I have extracted the PixelData from the image and want to convert it to a numpy array of appropriate shape using the following code:

```
image_bytes = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
PixelData = tfio.image.decode_dicom_data(image_bytes, tfio.image.dicom_tags.PixelData).numpy()
pixel_array = np.frombuffer(PixelData, dtype=tf.uint16)
pixel_array = np.reshape(pixel_array, (512,512))
print(pixel_array)
```

This code should be equivalent to

```
Image = pydicom.dcmread(image_path)
pixel_array = Image.pixel_array
print(pixel_array)
```

and

```
Image = pydicom.dcmread(image_path)
PixelData = Image.PixelData
pixel_array = np.frombuffer(PixelData, dtype=np.uint16)
pixel_array = np.reshape(pixel_array, (512,512))
print(pixel_array)
```

The DICOM tags are the same ones used by pydicom, and are given [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/io/api_docs/python/tfio/image/dicom_tags#PixelData). The PixelData should return the raw byte values of the DICOM image. I have confirmed through pydicom that the raw pixel data is stored as np.uint16 values. However, when I try to convert the byte data given by tensorflow into a numpy array using the np.frombuffer function, I get an error of buffer size not being divisible by the element length.

When I run the above scripts, these are the following output shapes

1. Tensorflow: Doesn't run with tf.uint16, gives output shape (1310719,) when using tf.uint8
2. Pydicom direct pixel_array: Output shape of (512,512)
3. Pydicom PixelData to pixel_array: Output shape of (512,512)

The pydicom examples provide identical outputs in both cases, however the tensorflow DICOM tag seems to provide a completely different result. Please find attached an example DICOM file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Agvj-qo2BzSXhfzYQaMtu7YCSfyoPx1g/view?usp=sharing). Is there something wrong with the library or my implementation?

Edit:
The DICOM images are actually signed 16 bit integers, not unsigned. Hence, the following three snippets of code produce the same output:

Direct pixel_array from pydicom

```
import pydicom
import numpy as np

dcm = pydicom.dcmread("ID_000012eaf.dcm")
print(dcm.pixel_array)
```

Converting PixelData to pixel_array manually

```
import pydicom
import numpy as np
dcm = pydicom.dcmread("ID_000012eaf.dcm")
PixelData = dcm.PixelData
pixel_array = np.frombuffer(PixelData, dtype=np.int16)
pixel_array = np.reshape(pixel_array, (512,512))
print(pixel_array)
```

Directly obtaining pixel_array using tensorflow_io

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio
import numpy as np
image_bytes = tf.io.read_file("ID_000012eaf.dcm")
pixel_array = tfio.image.decode_dicom_image(image_bytes, on_error='lossy', scale='preserve', dtype=tf.float32).numpy()
pixel_array = pixel_array.astype('int16')
pixel_array /= 2.
pixel_array = np.reshape(pixel_array, (512,512))
print(pixel_array)
```

However, this final snippet of code still doesn't work for some reason:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio
import numpy as np

image_bytes = tf.io.read_file("ID_000012eaf.dcm")
PixelData = tfio.image.decode_dicom_data(image_bytes, tfio.image.dicom_tags.PixelData).numpy()
pixel_array = np.frombuffer(PixelData, dtype=np.int16)
print(pixel_array)
```

Edit 2: These two snippets of code should theoretically work, however they display errors that the length of the byte string is not divisible by the size of int16:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio
import numpy as np
image_bytes = tf.io.read_file("ID_000012eaf.dcm")
PixelData = tfio.image.decode_dicom_data(image_bytes, tfio.image.dicom_tags.PixelData).numpy()
pixel_array =  np.frombuffer(PixelData, dtype=np.int16)
pixel_array = np.reshape(pixel_array, (512,512))
print(pixel_array)
```

and

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio
import numpy as np
image_bytes = tf.io.read_file("ID_000012eaf.dcm")
PixelData = tfio.image.decode_dicom_data(image_bytes, tfio.image.dicom_tags.PixelData)
pixel_array = tf.io.decode_raw(PixelData, tf.int16)
pixel_array = tf.reshape(pixel_array, (512,512))
print(pixel_array)
```

Edit 3: After getting the hint that the byte string provided by decode_dicom_data contains hexadecimal values, I found a way to convert my data into the desired pixel_array, but I'm curious why PixelData is stored this way:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio
import numpy as np
image_bytes = tf.io.read_file("ID_000012eaf.dcm")
PixelData = tfio.image.decode_dicom_data(image_bytes, tfio.image.dicom_tags.PixelData).numpy()
pixel_array = np.zeros(262144, dtype=np.int16)
start,stop = 0,4
for i in range(262144):
    pixel_array[i] = int(PixelData[start:stop], base=16)
    start+=5
    stop+=5
pixel_array = np.reshape(pixel_array, (512,512))
print(pixel_array)
```

PixelData from pydicom:

```
PixelData = b'0\xf80\xf80\xf80...'
```

PixelData from Tensorflow_io

```
PixelData = b'f830\\f830\\f830\\...'
```

Any suggestions for code refactoring and linting would be highly appreciated. I am extremely grateful to @ai2ys for helping me diagnose these issues.

Comment: Would you click on the “check mark“, if my answer below answers you question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `tfio.image.decode_dicom_data` decodes the tag information and not the pixel information.

To read the pixel data use `tfio.image.decode_dicom_image` instead.

```
import tensorflow_io as tfio

image_bytes = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
pixel_data = tfio.image.decode_dicom_image(
    image_bytes,
    dtype=tf.uint16)

# type conversion and reshaping is not required
# as can be checked with the print statement
print(pixel_data.dtype, pixel_data.shape)

# if required the pixel_data can be converted to a numpy array
# but calculations like scaling and offset correction can 
# be done on tensors as well
pixel_data_nparray = pixel_data.numpy()

# reading tag information, e.g. rescale intercept and slope
intersept = tfio.image.decode_dicom_data(
    image_bytes, 
    tfio.image.dicom_tags.RescaleIntercept)
slope = tfio.image.decode_dicom_data(
    image_bytes,
    tfio.image.dicom_tags.RescaleSlope)

print(intersept)
print(slope)
```

Please checkout the docs for further information:

- https://www.tensorflow.org/io/api_docs/python/tfio/image/decode_dicom_data
- https://www.tensorflow.org/io/api_docs/python/tfio/image/decode_dicom_image

Edit 2021-02-01 using the shared file:

It is also possible to read the pixel data using `tfio.image.decode_dicom_data` with passing `tfio.image.dicom_tags.PixelData` but the byte string getting returned has to be decoded.

```
data = tfio.image.decode_dicom_data(image_bytes, tfio.image.dicom_tags.PixelData)
print(data)
```

Output (shortened):

```
tf.Tensor(b'f830\\f830\\f830\\f830\\ ...')
```

The hex value `f830` interpreted as `int16` is `-2000`.

Comment: @KumareshBalaji Have you tried the Colab example that is referenced in the links from the documentation? https://www.tensorflow.org/io/tutorials/dicom

Comment: I've tried the solution which you suggested. For most of my files, the function gives an error despite being readable with pydicom. When I set the arguments on_error='lossy' and scale='auto', I am able to convert them to values which are close to the values provided by pydicom PixelData, but are still different to the pydicom pixel_array values. A link to my example DICOM image and codes is [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qAte3Vii-FmJi1Rukg0DAD1BgO_yNImb?usp=sharing)

Comment: Yes, I've tried the collab notebook given [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/io/tutorials/dicom). I've also linked the exact file and code that I used in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem:
The images which I have are of signed 16-bit integer data type, but no such option exists within the tensorflow_io library. After converting the array values to 16 bit signed numbers, the problem is resolved. I have to convert the data to a higher datatype like float32 in the decode_dicom_image function, recast to signed int16 in numpy and finally divide by 2(not sure why the last step), but I finally get a pixel_array which is identical to the output from pydicom.

Now everything makes sense except converting data from the dicom_tag PixelData, which still shows unexplained behaviour. I have updated the python scripts here showing the different DICOM image conversion methods with different libraries [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qAte3Vii-FmJi1Rukg0DAD1BgO_yNImb?usp=sharing) for anyone who is interested.

Comment: The PixelData does not really have unexplainable behaviour. It contains the data as well, but it has to be converted from a string containing the hex values and it has to be reshaped as well according to the dimensions.

Comment: @ai2ys Excellent, thank you for letting me know.